# Django Rest API JWT authentication - No active account found with the given credentials

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, jwt

I have a question concerning the Django Rest Framework JWT auth protocol.

This issue has been coming up a lot but no suggested solution has worked for me yet.

When I try this command:

> http post http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/token/ username=username password=password

or

> curl -X POST -d "username=username&password=password" http://localhost:8000/api/token/

to obtain the access/refresh tokens as suggested in many tutorials, I get this error:

> {
> "detail": "No active account found with the given credentials"
> }

1. I have created a superuser
2. My users are all is_active = True
3. My passwords are hashed in the database
4. I have AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'my_app_name.User' in settings.py
5. The username/password are 100% correct.

Here is my User model:

```
class User(LifecycleModelMixin, AbstractUser):
    public_id = models.UUIDField(unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    job_title = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    street_address = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    street_address2 = models.CharField(
        verbose_name="Street address 2", max_length=100, blank=True
    )
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True, null=True, blank=True)
    email_subscribed = models.BooleanField(default=True, null=True, blank=True)
    manager = models.ForeignKey(
        "self",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name="sub_users",
    )
    country = CountryField(blank_label="(select country)", blank=True)
    contact_info = JSONField("ContactInfo", default=contact_default)
```

My serializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = super().create(validated_data)
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        return user

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'username', 'refreshToken', 'password')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}
```

My urls:

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import (
    TokenObtainPairView,
    TokenRefreshView,
    TokenVerifyView,
)

urlpatterns: List[URLPattern] = (
    [
        path('api/token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
        path('api/token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
        path('api/token/verify/', TokenVerifyView.as_view(), name='token_verify'),
        path('api-token-auth/', obtain_auth_token, name='api_token_auth'), 
        path("auth/", include("authapp.urls")),
    ]
    + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
)
```

my settings.py:

```
DJANGO_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "django.contrib.sites",
    "django.forms",
]

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # styling
    "crispy_forms",
    "crispy_tailwind",
    "crispy_bootstrap5",
    "widget_tweaks",
    # rest framework
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    #celery
    "django_celery_beat",
    # dev
    "django_extensions",
    "debug_toolbar",
    # deploy
    "whitenoise.runserver_nostatic",
    # auth
    'authapp',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt',
    'djoser',
    "allauth",
    "allauth.account",
    "allauth.socialaccount",
    # mail
    "anymail",
    # utils
    "phonenumber_field",
    "simple_history",
    "markdownify",
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES':(
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    )
}
```

I am out of ideas as to why this is happening. This is my first experience with Django Rest Framework, therefore I suspect I might have forgotten to add something crucial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My colleague found the issue.

In my settings.py file my config for ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD is set to email.

settings.py:

```
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = "email"
```

So the HTTP command should look like this:

```
http http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/token/ username=email password=password
```

Yeah. It was that simple.